# Javascript does not display non-standard characters

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

So this is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> 
    function loadScript("http://www.qppstudio.net/individualdays/noscroll/2012-08-15.js") { 
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="', url, '">', '<', '/', 'script>'); 
    }   
</script>
```

Included in page header:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Page displays unicode characters without any problems expect for the part where posted javascript writes to page. Is the script changed somehow while being downloaded between different domains?

Comment: Is the JavaScript file send with UTF-8 charset from the server?

Comment: What unicode characters?

Comment: Are you trying to load a script using document.write?

Comment: The `url` variable is being used in your function, but it's not set anywhere in the code you provided.  I assume the URL string you've passed into the function is meant to stand in for this `url` variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably. This is the first time that I've seen the `charset` attribute. I'm not sure what you try to achieve with it. If the server sends you file with `iso-latin-1` encoding but you tell the browser the file has `UTF-8` encoding, what should happen? The browser won't convert the file from one encoding to the other; the best that you could hope for is that the browser tries to interpret the byte stream as `UTF-8` which will not work.

The correct solution is to configure the server to send the files with the correct encoding in the HTTP response header. The browser will look for this information and read the byte stream with the encoding specified there.

Don't forget to actually send the bytes in the correct encoding! This means: File reading, copying to the output stream + setting the encoding headers, everything must work perfectly or you will have odd bugs.

Comment: Yup, this was the case. iso-8859-1 was the answer. silly me :/